# How to show/hide filer for ng-repeat for AngularJs 1.4.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a list of messages with filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:searchForMessage">
```

and this is a button:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="search()">
        <img src="../common/magnifier.png">
</a>
```

but I would like to hide/show **this filter only** on click on the Search button:

```
$scope.showSearchPanel = false;
    $scope.search = function(){
        $scope.showSearchPanel = !$scope.showSearchPanel;
    }
```

Are there any way how I could do that?
Thank you!

Comment: ng-show / ng-if / ng-hide

Comment: You mean have the filter searchForMessage enable/disable on click?

Comment: Hide search panel/ Show search panel on click. Like: `ng-show="showSearchPanel == true" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<tr ng-if="showSearchPanel" ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:searchForMessage">
```

It will show after clicking on search button

Comment: what do you mean by search panel? you can add `ng-if="showSearchPanel"` condition on any element which you want to show / hide when clicking search button

Comment: Oh, I found that filter input is another one line of code at my example, fixed. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer as useful so that it helps others as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add the variable in the filter to switch it on and off.

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:searchForMessage: showSearchPanel">
```

Then inside the filter you can validate if "showSearchPanel" return filtered results otherwise return same results

Comment: This solution hides search results, but not the entire search panel (or may be I'm doing that wrong)